# Change the font color for the Skype panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, skype

So I just installed Skype and I'm using the Ambiance theme that comes with Ubuntu 10.10.

It looks like the font color for the text in the Skype panel is the same as the background color for panels in the Ambiance theme.

Is there any way to change the font color in the panel JUST for Skype?

I did a:

find . -name "*skype*"

and checked some of the conf files but didn't see anything related to text color.

Comment: What about the FONT type options. The IM option is missing from the left menu. WHY? why we cant change Font type for the Chat window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a confirmed Skype bug with the Ambiance theme. You can fix this by going into your Skype Options > General > Choose Style and set it to "Desktop Settings". I've posted a screenshot.

[image: A screenshot of what needs to be changed]